# php: cache mysql results for x minutes

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I build a block and it turns out to make a huge load on mysql and making tables to lock.
how can i cache mysql results into file or memory with php for X minutes?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dle_post WHERE (approve='1')  
                        AND (category LIKE 'something' $all_movies)
                        AND date >= '$monthagodate'  
                        AND date < '$curdate' + INTERVAL 1 day  
                        ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $more,$number_of_topics");
```

Comment: create a txt file and write all that in using fwrite and upon x minutes get them!

Comment: It would also be useful if you take the query and run it with EXPLAIN before. Chances are it can speed up tremendously with proper indexing.

Comment: as well as the above (proper indexing) you might find it's quicker, even though it doesn't sound ideal, to remove ORDER BY from the SQL and iterate the results in PHP to order them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MySQL query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) if your table data is not being updated frequently. Otherwise use [memcached](http://memcached.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time caching is not needed. And, in cases like yours, it will be just a crutch, not a proper solution.

If one created a query that makes a huge load on server, one have to *optimize* that query, not cache its results.

Run `explain` on this query and find out why it doesn't use indexes (if any).